# M*f(x) is not continuous

Tags: functional-analysis

Given  $f: R^n\to R $ an integrable function. Then the *centered maximal operator* is defined by
    $$M^{*}f(x)= \sup_{r>0} \dfrac{1}{\mu(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|\,d\mu(y) .$$

Here the supremum is taken over all the balls in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ centred at the point $x$.

I did prove that if the function $f$ is continuous the non-centered maximal function is continuous. But it is not true in the case of the centered maximal function. I spent the last week trying to find a counter example but I could not. Can some one give me a hint how to find one?
I will list some of the functions that I tried.

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}
2x, & x \in [0,1]\\
2,  & x \in [1,2]\\
0,  & \text{otherwise}   
\end{cases}.$$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
      x^2, & x \in [0,1]\\
      \dfrac{1+x}{2}, & x \in [1,2]\\
      0,  & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: I think I had to construct a 2D example of this years ago. You might try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an easy counterexample with $n=1$ and $f(x)=1_{[0,1]}$. Then 
$$
Mf(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{2|x-1|},&\ x\leq0,\\ \ \\ 1,&\ x\in(0,1)\\ \ \\
\frac1{2|x|},&\ x\geq1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: The function $f$ is not cont at $x=0 , 1$. I need an example of $f$ to be a  continuous function, where $M*f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Neither are the examples you wrote in your question, so why would you consider them?

Comment: both of the examples are continuous at $x=1$. But the centred maximal function is continuous is also continuous . I need an example for a continuous function at a point where the centred maximal function at that point is not continuous.